# PHP - What is an event manager?

Tags: php, cakephp, zend-framework, symfony

I have seen in a number of PHP frameworks the use of "event manager" classes. What exactly is an event manager within the scope of a "normal" MVC framework and what does it offer to the application in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First have a [read about event driven programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) to understand the basic idea.

I think every of the frameworks you've tagged has a manual page about the event system as well. At least [CakePHP has a pretty detailed one](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/events.html) about it's event system and it's [event manager](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-CakeEventManager.html). The description of it is already half of an explanation what an event manager is:

> The event manager is responsible for keeping track of event listeners,
>   passing the correct data to them, and firing them in the correct
>   order, when associated events are triggered. You can create multiple
>   instances of this object to manage local events or keep a single
>   instance and pass it around to manage all events in your app.

An event manager can attach listeners, or receivers, objects that listens or are "connected" to events. When an event is fired and dispatched by the event manager all listeners that are registered to one or more events will receive the event object instance and can work with it.

**Be careful with events**, *correctly* used they're great, *inappropriate* used they can make your application a hard to debug and hard to understand mess. Don't use them just because they're cool, document the events in your application.

[Here is an example of how to inject additional fields into a form](http://florian-kraemer.net/2014/01/callbacks-in-cakephp-forms-using-events/) using the CakePHP event system. This use case might suit a CMS or if you have to conditionally add something to a form through a plugin system.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, an event manager allows separate parts of the application to be aware of actions.

Say I have a module for a payment provider. The payment provider calls a private url to return the status of the payment. Once I've verified the status of the payment, I fire off an event to indicate something has been paid.

The code responsible for handling the customer side of the transaction can listen to those events and for example send the email that the customer has paid and generate invoices.

Answer (score 1):

In a, very small, nutshell, an event manager provides a way of storing events in an application, providing for event driven programming. You can take advantage of registered events by developing functionality which listens for them and reacts accordingly. When used properly, an event manager helps decouple code and make it leaner and more reusable.

For example, say you have written a blogging module for a client, which allows you to manage simple posts. If you then need to send a tweet when a post is published, you can register an event which fires on post publish, then write a process which listens for that event, and sends a tweet. Neither process need know of the other, as logically it's not necessary. Both can be developed and tested separately, yet work together.